# What are the vacuum Einstein's equations?

Tags: general-relativity, vacuum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I read on Wikipedia that if the Stress-Energy Tensor is set to zero in [General Relativity's Field Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) that it makes the Vacuum Equations. What are these equations, and how are they used?

Comment: The vacuum equations are the same Einstein equations with $T_{\mu \nu}=0$.

Comment: The Einstein field equations relate a geometric quantity, the Einstein tensor $G_{\mu\nu}$ to the stress-energy of a system, $T_{\mu\nu}$ as $G_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi G \, T_{\mu\nu}$, in natural units. If the stress-energy is zero, that essentially corresponds to a vacuum, and the equation becomes $G_{\mu\nu} = 0$. These equations are used to either solve for  how a spacetime is deformed given some matter content, or to compute the matter giving rise to a known spacetime, depending on which is known *a priori*.

Comment: You have answered yourself the "what"-part. Regarding how they are used -  e.g. they are the main way for studying classical black holes, their basic solutions are used to determine quantitative differences between GR and Newtonian Gravity, using them one may "come up" with simple cosmological models of an "empty universe", etc.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. "If the stress-energy tensor is set to zero in the [...] field equation that makes it the vacuum equation" - you just gave the definition of the vacuum equations, why are you asking what they are?

Comment: Setting the source term, which is the stress-energy tensor, to zero is analogous to setting the electric charge density to zero in the equation for the electric potential:  $\nabla^2 \Phi = -\rho / \varepsilon_0 = 0$.  Solving this equation in spherical coordinates (with appropriate boundary conditions)  gives the potential due to point charge at the origin.  Similarly, solving $G_{\mu \nu} = 0$ for a spherically symmetric spacetime yields the metric for a 'point mass at the origin' (a Schwarzschild black hole actually).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vacuum Einstein equation is just
$$ G^{\mu\nu} = 0 \,.$$

Of course, that does not help much, if one does not specify this tensor. That is given by
$$ G^{\mu\nu} = R^{\mu\nu} - \frac 12 \mathcal Rg^{\mu\nu} \,.$$

Then we need to specify the Ricci tensor and the Ricci scalar. Those are
$$ \mathcal R = g^{\nu\beta} R_{\nu\beta} \qquad\text{and}\qquad R_{\nu\beta} = R^\alpha{}_{\nu\alpha\beta} \,.$$

Then we need the Riemann curvature tensor (the one with four indices). That is
$$ R^\mu{}_{\nu\alpha\beta} = \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\beta,\alpha} -
    \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\alpha,\beta} + \Gamma^\mu_{\lambda\alpha}
    \Gamma^\lambda_{\nu\beta} - \Gamma^\mu_{\lambda\beta}
    \Gamma^\lambda_{\nu\alpha} \,.$$

The Christoffel symbols are given by
$$ \Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^\mu = \frac12 g^{\mu\delta} [g_{\delta\alpha,\beta} +
    g_{\delta\beta,\alpha} - g_{\alpha\beta,\delta}] \,.$$
The notation with the comma in the subscript is a partial derivative, $X_{,\mu} = \partial_\mu X$.

If you plug everything in, you have the vacuum Einstein equation. In practice, one will have to make an ansatz for $g_{\mu\nu}$ and see whether it works out. You end up with ten coupled non-linear second-order partial differential equations. You cannot solve that in the general case, therefore one needs to either solve simple systems (Schwarzschild black hole) or simplify the equations until one can have graviational waves.